# MSI installer not installing mongod.exe

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently trying to install MongoDB using the MSI installer. I want to install the server component without the windows-service (we will run the mongod.exe ourselves)

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows-unattended/) I should only have to use `Server` in the `ADDLOCAL` parameter. Unfortunately the mongod.exe file is missing from the installation directory when using the following command:

> msiexec /qb /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.5-signed.msi
>   SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0" ADDLOCAL="Server"

[image: MongoDB installation folder]

Adding `ServerService` to the `ADDLOCAL` parameter will copy the mongod.exe file to the installation folder but will also create a windows-service (which I don't need nor want)

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this a bug in the installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-39025) in v4.0.5 which has been fixed in the versions 4.0.10 and 4.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Try the link for the Enterprise version:

`https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise/releases`